# Ajuda com onitemclick listview

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando fazer com que um `Toast` apareça logo que usuário escolher uma opção do `Listview`, porém, quando o usuário escolhe a opção, é carregado primeiro a `Acticity` para depois aparecer o `Toast`, e o que eu realmente quero é o contrário.

Segue o código:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    int layout = R.layout.toast_custom;
                    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root);
                    view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup);
                    TextView tv_texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texto);
                    TextView slogan_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slogan);
                    tv_texto.setText("Aguarde...");
                    slogan_text.setText("Carregando " + opcoes[position]);
                    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
          if (opcoes[position] == 1){
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(view);
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Eventos.class);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
}
```

Como fazer com que primeiro se execute o `Toast` para depois iniciar a `Activity`?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524836/start-activity-after-toast-message

Comment: Valeu @DiegoFelipe exatamente isso! Obrigado.

Comment: @diegofm escreve uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que uma asyncTask resolva:

```
if (opcoes[position] == 1){             
    new AsyncTask().execute();    
}
```

...

```
private class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setView(view);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Eventos.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Espero que ajude.